# Random insane bad execution plans in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

Hi together I know that issue has been discussed for several times, but we face an insane weird issue on our new SQL Server 2014 SP3 right now, and we just can't get behind.

We switched over from Oracle to MS SQL Server last year. Our mayor DB is quite big, abt. 800GB, big tables, PDM system. +1000 active users. 16 cores, 192 GB Memory, SSD SAN Storage. ESX 6.5

Settings in SQL Server:

- Create Auto Statistics Enabled
- optimize for Ad Hoc Queries = true
- Snapshot Isolation enabled
- Max Parallel = 4
- Threshold 50
- Statistics Updates async in TempDB, normally enabled on our main DBs.

Any how, we have some queries which are handled extremly bad. All leads to the fact that the SQl Server Optimizer creates an execution plan, thinks its okay but on execution it does an inner join (or multiples) with Millions instead of expected 1-2 rows. And of cours millions of logical reads. And I can't get behind whats ongoing in this. These statements ran minutes then.

So basically, we have already 3 databases. All same version and hardware, Prod Test and Dev Environment. My tests can be done pretty easily. All dbs are configured the same and show the same behaviour, but on different queries. Lets say somethimes the test environment does the same statement multipletimes in 47s, the prod db in just a second. Others take seconds in Prod, are instand in Test. What the heck is going on? I always retry the statements muliple times to ensure its cached.

The query is generated by the 4 Tier Application we are using.

- Query - https://pastebin.com/fefxXgND
- 1 sec plan - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJvCsgPm4
- 47 sec plan - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1cP2ev7N

1s vs 47s. Both of these DBs share the same SQL Instance. The weird thing is that it might be instant as well if we reset the plan cache. But any how, it slows down again by a complete mess of misscalculation in the optimizer.

Any ideas what could have been wrong here? How to correct single execution plans? How can it be that the sql server doenst learn from that extremly bad statement and to correct it the next time it runs?

---

I have switched over and rebooted the Test DB with standard trace flags, so no compatibility mode.

Detailed DB settings are:
[image]

Initially the query runs for 10 minutes... first run. Now it cached instantly as well.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syhb_Vvm4

```
DBCC TRACEOFF(9481)
SELECT  DISTINCT t_08.puid 
FROM PWORKSPACEOBJECT t_06 
, PRELEASE_STATUS_LIST t_07 
, PITEMREVISION t_08 
, PRELEASESTATUS t_02 
, PE9_MANUFACTURERSTORAGE t_09 
, PEN_ITEMREVMASTER t_01 
, PFORM t_05 
, PIMANRELATION t_03 
, PIMANRELATION t_04 
WHERE ( (  UPPER(t_06.pobject_type)  IN  ( UPPER( 'EN_Item Revision' ) ,  UPPER( 'EN_Item Revision' )  ) 
AND ( ( ( t_07.pvalu_0 = t_02.puid ) 
AND  UPPER(t_02.pname)  IN  ( UPPER( 'V' ) ,  UPPER( 'E9_D' ) ,  UPPER( 'F' ) ,  UPPER( 'E9_to_F' ) ,  UPPER( 'E9_M' )  ) ) 
AND ( ( ( t_08.puid = t_03.rprimary_objectu ) 
AND ( ( t_03.rrelation_typeu = 'gMx8h03uVJFL2B' ) 
AND ( ( t_03.rsecondary_objectu = t_05.puid ) 
AND ( ( t_05.rdata_fileu = t_01.puid ) 
AND ( ( t_01.re9_manufactureru = t_09.puid ) 
AND  ( UPPER(t_09.pe9_id)  =  UPPER( '7300007' )  ) ) ) ) ) ) 
AND ( ( t_08.puid = t_04.rprimary_objectu ) 
AND ( ( t_04.rrelation_typeu = 'gMx8h03uVJFL2B' ) 
AND ( ( t_04.rsecondary_objectu = t_05.puid ) 
AND ( ( t_05.rdata_fileu = t_01.puid ) 
AND  ( UPPER(t_01.phersteller_artikelnr)  =  UPPER( '00100893' )  ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) AND ( t_06.puid = t_07.puid AND t_07.puid = t_08.puid ) );
```

but that should be the same like now.

What could it be if the first queries against the DB are lightening fast in the beginning and at later on it slows down by factor 50 as it does a weird execution plan?

---

With the standard CE in our test environment enabled + a required wipe of the plan cache, the statement above runs instantly on our test environment using the "good plan".

This whole topic, including the test with the older CE in "test", came up due to the fact that if we create a single most likely required index in our production environment, a bad execution plan is created, similar to the bad one above, causing 100% cpu load within three minutes and we had to kill all sessions 3 times during working time now, even as a MS SQL expert created that index in good mood.

The missing index statement was this:

```
WITH cte_00000000059A53B0_17 AS (
         SELECT t_03.puid AS revPuid
               ,t_04.pdate_released AS revDateRel
               ,t_03.ritems_tagu AS myItem
               ,t_04.puid AS rlsPuid
               ,t_04.pname AS rlsName
         FROM   PWORKSPACEOBJECT t_01
               ,PRELEASE_STATUS_LIST t_02
               ,PITEMREVISION t_03
               ,PRELEASESTATUS t_04
               ,#PRefbindtag3
         WHERE  (
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                (
                                    t_03.ritems_tagu = #PRefbindtag3.puid
                                    AND (t_04.pdate_released <= @P1)
                                )
                                AND (t_04.pname = @P2)
                            )
                            AND (t_02.pvalu_0 = t_04.puid)
                        )
                        AND (t_01.pactive_seq != 0)
                    )
                    AND (t_01.puid = t_02.puid AND t_02.puid = t_03.puid)
                )
     )

SELECT DISTINCT t_07.myItem
      ,t_07.revPuid
      ,t_06.rDate
      ,t_07.rlsPuid
FROM   cte_00000000059A53B0_17 t_07
      ,(
           SELECT MAX(t_05.revDateRel) AS rDate
                 ,t_05.myItem AS dtItem
           FROM   cte_00000000059A53B0_17 t_05
           GROUP BY
                  t_05.myItem
       ) t_06
WHERE  (
           (
               (t_07.myItem = t_06.dtItem)
               AND (t_07.revDateRel = t_06.rDate)
           )
           AND (t_07.rlsName = @P3)
       )
ORDER BY
       t_06.rDate DESC
```

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJJhK4dmN

```
USE [TCEUP01]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[PRELEASESTATUS] ([pname],[pdate_released])
INCLUDE ([puid])
GO
```

We need to try the same with a complete DB restart on weekend as we cant see that weird plan in our test environment having this Index enabled. Statistics are a good point, I'll verify if they were all updated. Any ideas on this?

---

Edit:

Sadly we dont seem to have a solution yet. What we inestigated the last weeks:

-> we found out that some date / time colums were not migrated correctly from oracle, they had no hour and minutes time stamps so all have been on date and 0:00. The in general high load on our production environment dropped fixing the affected tables. I expect the queries got far less data to compute once the dates have been more atomic.

-> we were pretty optimistic that the highly suggested Index creation, who caused out prod db to stuck, now will be created without any issue on less than 10% Db CPU load.

-> we created it yesterday after working hours so less load on the DB. Within minutes we sould see some active CTE statements having billion, seriously billions of logical reads and they did not shift to resent at all. It seems that it have been always the 4 same process IDs but as said, they crank up some cores to 100% and keep running. We did not do a flush of the whole execution plan cache as we saw the plans they use are new.

-> I could only grab  of the active statements and save their execution plan. sadly this should be the expected, not the real execution plan or?

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkWRKSFN4

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryCJ9BtNE

The new index was named: EN_PIPRELEASESTATUS_1

So any how, this Index causes our prod Db to stuck in hefty plans, while the identical test environment runs fine.

ideas? Thanks

Btw: We could drop the indey by

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

  -- lock table "a" till end of transaction
  SELECT top 1 puid
  FROM PRELEASESTATUS
  WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
  -- do some other stuff (including inserting/updating table "a")
  DROP INDEX [EN_PIPRELEASESTATUS_1] ON [dbo].[PRELEASESTATUS]
  -- release lock
  COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO
```

I took a screenshot of some sessions going crazy, that was on the very beginning
[image]

Comment: Can you please upload the plans to PasteThePlan.com and replace your screenshots? The screenshots don't contain any of the useful meta data needed to properly diagnose the problem.

Comment: thx, give me a min and they will be there.

Comment: I added them in the first post

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` after a 9-tables join. The ORMs and their pitfalls ;)

Comment: yeah. I even have the opposite example wher ethe productive system is way slower than the test system. ill try to attach the same here. Prolem goes on... if i create a single index (highly missing regadring to different tools) my productive database maxes out and stucks due to 100% load. Smees like several execution plans get the same issue then and produce mrd of logical reads. That caused our system to stuck 2 times now . So i can see the same issue in both directions. I can harly imagine how the same statement can be that mich differently handled and performing.

Comment: I also know the "good" system in the example above currently  is in parallel as the estiminated cost is >50, while the bad system expect it to be 0,0XX and therefore never switched to parallel execution. We also played with the CE setting to see if it does a difference. But that cant be fixed currently.

Comment: For a proper analysis, the `CREATE TABLE` statements - including all indexes - would be needed as well and table sizes (number of rows). Since there are  8 tables involved, it would make the question quite long. I suggest you post that at pastebin or similar site and add the link in the question.

Comment: Have you checked that your statistics are up to date?

Comment: In the fast plan it joins `t_09` and `t_01` first and that reduces it down to 1 row and all the other joins have to do negligible amounts of work.

In the slow one (surprisingly) despite the `UPPER` it still seeks into `t_06.pobject_type` but then the estimates are way off (1 vs 2,153,031 rows)

Comment: What is `PIPWORKSPACEOBJ_0`? Is that an indexed computed column with `UPPER`?

Comment: ill check though your comments and answer later on. With the standard 120 CE enabled, thi specific issue on the listed statement was solved - but we face an identical issue in our prod with that ce enabled, but on a different query (WITH CTE statement). Ill add the same. This is the reason why im seaching, if we add a highly important index in our production environment, a bad plan appears freezing the db by bumping the CPU to 100% due to massive inner joins. You cant even delete that index then without closing all sessions. I will update the original post.

Comment: ill update all tables statistics in our production environment this weekend to ensure they are up to date. Next time we create that index, ill flush the plan cache afterwards to ensure that new plans are created, based on new indexes and statistics.

Comment: yep. You need to look into the 1 vs 2,153,031 rows discrepancy. Probably updating stats will do it

Comment: we just found the real difference. It seems like some tables have been migrated differently from oracle. so the timestamps of few important tables lost the hours and minutes information. (date time stuff). That lead to the fact that the same queries caused way more computing efford.

Comment: added some information to the original post. Sadly that did not fix our issue creating the index in our prod environment as , any how, a plan with billions of logical reads get created as soon as the new index is there.

Answer (score 3):

Your database settings are DIFFERENT.

Your first plan is produced on database with `compatibility level` = 120:

```
CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="120"
```

And your second plan was produced by using `legacy cardinality estimator`:

```
CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70"
```

So you can change database `compatibility level` to `120` on the second database (it will affect all the queries) or use query hint `(QUERYTRACEON 2312)` (it will affect only this query)
as described here: [Enable plan-affecting SQL Server query optimizer behavior that can be controlled by different trace flags on a specific-query level](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2801413/enable-plan-affecting-sql-server-query-optimizer-behavior-that-can-be)

> Trace flag 2312 forces the query optimizer to use version 120 (the SQL
>   Server 2014 version) of the cardinality estimator when creating the
>   query plan.

But the main issue that I see in your query is that you used `Oracle approach` to write it.

You should not use `UPPER()` unless your database use case sensitive collation.

For example, `UPPER(t_06.pobject_type)`  should be rewritten as simple `t_06.pobject_type`, when you apply any function to a field you successfully exclude indexes on this field from using them.

`SQL Server` is NOT `Oracle`, case-sensitive collations are rarely used.

The second observation regards the number of joins in your query.

When you have more than 5 tables, optimizer has no chance to find good enough plan in small time, so it can stop optimization with the reason `StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="TimeOut"` that I found in one of your plans.

Split your query in two, start the first from smallest table (smallest after filtering), `PE9_MANUFACTURERSTORAGE t_09` in your case, join non more than 4 tables to it and save the result in temporary table. Then use this temp table to join other tables.

**UPDATE**

On the last picture that you posted as the answer your `db collation` IS `CASE SENSITIVE`. I don't know why did you choose `binary collation`, it's the fastest collation but if you don't want to use correct case and use `UPPER()` indexes will not be used. On other side, if you use `UPPER()` it seems that you don't want this case sensitivity, so why did you choose `binary`?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Yeah, I am aware of that fact with CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70" but we tried that on our test system yesterday, its still active but made no difference . We will until this lunch time once nobody is on that test environment.

On the statements itself we only have rare influence as they are produced by Siemens. We only request the data by a defined API and they can handle with SQL, no matter if they do good or bad, in most cases I have to deal with the statements they do.

Comment: I think “*please stop to use UPPER*”  should probably be “*please stop using UPPER*”?  They mean opposite things, so it seems a bit confusing right now...

Comment: @RBarryYoung Sorry, my English is bad, I still cannot understand the difference, it seems to me that both the phrases means the same. I wanted to say "You should not use UPPER unless your database use case sensitive collation"

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be the case, just trying to help.  Either your last sentence or my suggested change should work.  The original phrase is awkward but technically means the reverse of what I think that you intended.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thank you, I'll edit my answer with the "should" phrase :)

Comment: our DB has a case sensitive collation. Its a requirement by our application (Teamcenter).

Comment: >>>our DB has a case sensitive collation<<< I made an update in my answer, please see in bold